# Вебсервер не видит виртуальный хост

Tags: apache, vps, virtual-hosts

Вебсервер не видит виртуальный хост. Настройка виртуального хоста:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/webmail.*****.info.conf

====================================================

```
< VirtualHost *>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/webmail"

ServerName webmail.*****.info

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/html/webmail">

allow from all

Options None

Require all granted

< /Directory>

< /VirtualHost>
```

====================================================

Настройка a-record в GoDaddy:

1.

```
Type : A

Name : @ 

Value: 173.254.111.111

TTL: 600 seconds
```

2.

```
Type : A

Name : webmail

Value: 173.254.111.111 

TTL: 600 seconds
```

====================================================================

etc/hosts:

```
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes

ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

173.254.111.111  p*****.info  p*****

::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

При вызове webmail.*****.info и *****.info Переход осуществляется всегда на одну и туже папку: /var/www/html/

В каких настройках я ошибся?

Comment: в `sites-enabled` симлинк есть?

Comment: @vp_arth 
в sites-enabled симлинка нет к сожалению. Симлинк сюда нужен?
/etc/apache2/sites-available/webmail.*****.info.conf

Comment: Да, для этого обычно есть утилита `a2ensite webmail.*****`

Comment: @vp_arth . Сделал. Симлинк создался, Апача передёрнул, но не помогло. На webmail по-прежнему ноль внимания.

Comment: Ошибок не было при "передёргивании" апача?

Comment: @vp_arth сначала были, потом поправил и всё прошло нормально. Скажите, коллега, а a-record в GoDaddy в данном случае не лишний?

Comment: Корневой(@), возможно лишний, он резольвит *****.info в ваш IP